# Cannot get useAuthState() or useIdToken() from react-firebase-hooks to work consistently

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, react-firebase-hooks

These two hooks will regularly, but not all the time, return an indeterminate state. That is, `user` is `null`; `loading` is `false`; and `error` is `null`.

This occurs when logging in with Google. It navigates successfully to the Google login page and no errors occur when redirecting back. `loading` switches from `true` to `false`, but `user` and `error` are both null.

This is an intermittent problem, happening seemingly according to no obvious pattern.

My particular use case is not important, since I can recreate it easily with the sample code, which I have here:

```
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from 'firebase/auth';
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';

const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)

const login = () => {
  signInWithRedirect(auth, new GoogleAuthProvider());
};
const logout = () => {
  signOut(auth)
};

const CurrentUser = () => {
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Initialising User...</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (error) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Error: {error}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (user) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Current User: {user.email}</p>
        <button onClick={logout}>Log out</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <button onClick={login}>Log in</button>;
};
```

My code is not doing anything exotic. I have:

```
export const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

and have checked the `firebaseConfig` carefully for correctness.

Comment: Looks like you already [raised an issue with react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/issues/316). Given [the project appears abandoned](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/issues/310), I don't like your chances

Answer (score -1):

Personally I do not use `react-firebase-hooks`.  I have helped many people dealing with issues using the package.  IMO, it does not provide sufficient benefit above using the core Firebase Web Client SDKs to make it worth it.

I recommend you make use of the `onAuthStateChanged()` listener in your own code so that your code is capturing the completion of the Authentication process and you then get the `user` value directly yourself.

Here is [a sample project](https://github.com/gregfenton/react-and-user-profiles-with-firebase-auth-and-firestore) you could look to that showcases this use.  Take a look at the AuthProvider.jsx code for how it registers the `onAuthStateChanged()` listener, and how it is invoked in App.jsx.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've cloned it, going to take a look.

Comment: Hmm...I am using tsx, and there are all sorts of property mismatches...

Comment: Well that appears to suffer from a similar problem. Dropping in those two providers directly does not work too well; time to write my own!

Comment: I have created another post with my own implementation (still not working): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77728193/onauthstatechanged-from-firebase-sometimes-returns-a-null-user