# onAuthStateChanged() from Firebase sometimes returns a null user

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I have spent all day trying to pin this down.

`onAuthStateChanged()` from the Firebase SDK sometimes sends a `null` user to its function parameter. There appears to be no pattern: not dependent on browser or anything of that sort.

Of course, immediately I think there is a timing issue in my code, but I am also able to reproduce the problem using other libraries, such as [this one](https://github.com/gregfenton/react-and-user-profiles-with-firebase-auth-and-firestore) and [react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks).

I [posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77724083/cannot-get-useauthstate-or-useidtoken-from-react-firebase-hooks-to-work-cons), the result of which is that I wrote the code below.

So I believe there to be. configuration issue somewhere: that it only happens occasionally makes me believe it is not within my code, but this is blocking me.

Once a `null` user is returned, no other user is returned, so it's not like I can even set a flag to mitigate this problem.

```
import { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Auth, getAuth, IdTokenResult, onAuthStateChanged, User } from 'firebase/auth';
import { FirebaseContext, Props } from './FirebaseProvider';
import { Claims } from './Claims';

export type AuthContext = {
  auth: Auth | null,
  authLoading: boolean,
  idTokenResult: IdTokenResult | null,
  hasClaim: (claim: Claims) => boolean,
  user: User | null
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContext>({
  auth: null,
  authLoading: true,
  idTokenResult: null,
  hasClaim: null,
  user: null
});

export const AuthProvider = (props: Props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const firebaseApp = useContext(FirebaseContext);
  const [authInitializing, setAuthInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<Auth | null>(null);
  const [authLoading, setAuthLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [idTokenResult, setIdTokenResult] = useState<IdTokenResult | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firebaseApp !== null) {
      setAuth(getAuth());
      setAuthInitializing(false);
    }
  }, [firebaseApp]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth !== null) {
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        setUser(user);
        setAuthLoading(false);
      });
    }
  }, [auth]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user !== null) {
      user.getIdTokenResult().then(idTokenResult => setIdTokenResult(idTokenResult));
    } else {
      setIdTokenResult(null);
    }
  }, [user]);

  const hasClaim = useCallback((claim: Claims) => {
    if (idTokenResult === null) return false;
    return idTokenResult.claims[claim] === true;
  }, [idTokenResult]);

  const providerValues = {
    auth,
    authLoading,
    hasClaim,
    idTokenResult,
    user
  };

  if (authInitializing) {
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={providerValues}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) returns an unsubscribe function which you aren't using in your hook (and you should, otherwise it will just keep adding new listeners). Do you think that might be a problem?

Comment: Thank you, yes I had already added that last night. Doesn’t fix this issue; of course. I found the solution anyway, will post later.